# Caracteres especiales en tablas externas de Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

Tengo una tabla externa de campos fijos. El archivo tiene un caracter especial que ocasiona que los valores se desplazan en una posición.
Al cargar el plano el caracter "ñ" toma dos 2 bytes "??". Encontré que debo incluir CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8 STRING SIZES ARE IN CHARACTERS en la creación de la tabla externa
pero si bien ahora solo aparece en vez de la "ñ" un byte "?", el siguiente campo aun se sigue desplazando en una posición. Mis parámetros de BD son:

- NLS_CHARACTERSET: WE8MSWIN1252
- NLS_LANGUAGE: AMERICAN
- El plano esta en UTF-8.

```
create table EXT_RO_ORDENANTE
(
  tiporelacionordenante   varchar2(1),
  condresidenciaordenante varchar2(1),
  tipopersonaordenante    varchar2(1),
  tipodocumentoordenante  varchar2(1),
  numdocumentoordenante   varchar2(12),
  numrucordenante         varchar2(11),
  apepaternoordenante     varchar2(50),
  apematernoordenante     varchar2(40),
  nombresordenante        varchar2(40),
  profesionordenante      varchar2(4),
  paisnacordenante        varchar2(6),
  descpepordenante        varchar2(104),
  pepordenante            varchar2(2),
  direccionordenante      varchar2(150),
  departamentoordenante   varchar2(2),
  provinciaordenante      varchar2(2),
  distritoordenante       varchar2(2),
  telefonoordenante       varchar2(40),
  secuencia               varchar2(30),
  tipotrx                 varchar2(2)
)
organization external
(
  type ORACLE_LOADER
  default directory DIR_ESBS_IN
  access parameters 
  (
    records delimited by newline
    CHARACTERSET AL32UTF8
    STRING SIZES ARE IN CHARACTERS
    LOAD WHEN ((1:1) = '2')
    fields notrim
    (tipoRelacionOrdenante     (3:3)       char(1),
    condResidenciaOrdenante     (4:4)      char(1),
    tipoPersonaOrdenante        (5:5)      char(1),
    tipoDocumentoOrdenante      (6:6)      char(1),
    NumDocumentoOrdenante       (7:18)      char(12),
    NumRucOrdenante             (19:29)      char(11),
    ApePaternoOrdenante         (30:79)      char(50),
    ApeMaternoOrdenante         (80:119)      char(40),
    NombresOrdenante            (120:159)      char(40),
    ProfesionOrdenante          (160:163)      char(4),
    PaisNacOrdenante            (164:169)      char(6) ,
    descPepOrdenante            (170:273)      char(104),
    PepOrdenante                (274:275)      char(2) ,
    direccionOrdenante          (276:425)      char(150),
    departamentoOrdenante       (426:427)      char(2),
    provinciaOrdenante          (428:429)      char(2),
    distritoOrdenante           (430:431)      char(2),
    telefonoOrdenante           (432:471)      char(40),
    secuencia                   (472:501)      char(30),
    tipotrx                     (502:503)      char(2)
    )
  )
  location (DIR_ESBS_IN:'ROROPE2240020210228.txt')
)
REJECT LIMIT 0[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

En lugar de irse por la opción de posiciones recomendaría que el archivo a leer fuera delimitado por un carácter ya sea coma ,  pipeline o cualquier otro  , incluir que el dato pueda estar englobado por comillas ,  de está manera podrás evitar muchos problemas de lectura de caracteres especiales

Ejemplo de instrucción :

```
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ","  OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' LRTRIM
```